# Insert in catch block causes error: The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, transactions, try-catch

I have two procedures, one outer procedure and one inner procedure, where I would like to understand the behaviour of the error handling. The inner procedure provokes an error and is trying to insert something in the catch block into a table. After that the error is raised, passed to the outer procedure and then should roll back the transaction.

I'm trying to understand why my code is throwing the error message:

```
Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Procedure dbo.OuterProcedure, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 9]
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
```

I would expect the following message:

```
Msg 50000, Level 11, State 1, Procedure dbo.OuterProcedure, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 9]
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

I know that the issue comes from the catch block in the inner procedure and it happens because I'm trying to insert something into my log table before raising the error. When I switch those statements or delete the insert, I get the actual error message. I also know that it is not smart to do the logging in the inner procedure and inside a transaction that is rolled back anyways.

***I would like to understand what is making this transaction a "doomed" transaction even though the XACT_ABORT is set to off.***

**Full code:**

My main procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OuterProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION ;

        -- do other stuff 

        EXEC [dbo].[innerprocedure];

        -- do other stuff 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE @ErrText NVARCHAR(2000);
        SET @ErrText = ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'nothing')
        RAISERROR(@ErrText, 11, 1) WITH NOWAIT
    END CATCH;

END;
```

My inner procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InnerProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    BEGIN TRY
    -- do other stuff 

    -- provoke error
        SELECT 
              CASE
                  WHEN 1 = 0
                  THEN 0.0
                  ELSE ''
              END;

    -- do other stuff 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @ErrText NVARCHAR(2000);

        SELECT 
              @ErrText = ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'nothing');

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[logtable]
        ( 
              [Message]
            , [ErrNr]
        ) 
        VALUES
        ( @ErrText
        , -1
        );

        RAISERROR(@LogText, 11, 0) WITH NOWAIT;
    END CATCH;
END;
```

Comment: The above isn't really realistic. Why do you have an explicit transaction in the outer procedure when it does nothing transactional? The transaction should be in the inner query. When you get an error, then the `INSERT` to the table `logtable` would be written, and then when the error hits the outer procedure it would be rolled  back by *it's* error handler.

Comment: Also you should really be using `THROW`. `RAISERROR` does not respect `SET XACT_ABORT`, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"The **RAISERROR** statement does not honor **SET XACT_ABORT**. New applications should use **THROW** instead of **RAISERROR**."*

Comment: I know that the procedures aren't realistic, I just made them to figure out and reproduce an actual issue I had in a far more complex query. The outer procedure does only call the inner procedure as one of many other steps and the error occurs "naturally". I will indicate it in the code to provide some further clarity.

Comment: None of this changes my points though, @Chris. The outer procedure will `ROLLBACK` the `INSERT` into the table `dbo.LogTable`; making the `INSERT` pointless, *and* you are using a function (`RAISERROR`) which is specifically documented to not honour a feature you are using (`SET XACT_ABORT`).

Comment: I totally get your points and fully agree! It is nonsensical code to begin with. I just can not understand why the above error (The current transaction cannot be committed) is thrown even though I am not commiting my transaction. Using `THROW` instead of `RAISEERROR` does not change the behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to understand what is making this transaction a "doomed"
> transaction even though the XACT_ABORT is set to off.

`XACT_STATE()` is `-1` in the catch block so the transaction is doomed.

```
  SELECT 
      CASE
          WHEN 1 = 0
          THEN 0.0
          ELSE ''
      END;
```

Throws error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

"Most conversion errors" is one of the error types that [Erland Sommarskog puts](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#BatchTranAbort) in the category of errors.

> **Batch Abortion with Rollback** This is the strongest reaction SQL Server
> can take to a user error. These are errors that abort execution on the
> spot if there is no CATCH handler on the stack and they also roll back
> any open transaction. If there is a CATCH handler, the error is
> caught, but **any open transaction is doomed** and must be rolled back.
> The behaviour is the same, **no matter whether XACT_ABORT is ON or OFF**.

The categorisation of error behaviours is somewhat cryptic, undocumented and not intuitive. Read his article for more details.